# Как загрузить спрайт

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я нарисовал блок земли в Paint'e и хочу его вставить в 2д платформер в качестве пола, как мне это сделать? Или нужно как то рисовать в другом редакторе? Нужна помощь!!
З.Ы. Платформер я делаю для тренировки в создании игр

Comment: [Оно](https://docs.unity3d.com/530/Documentation/ScriptReference/Texture2D.LoadImage.html)?

Comment: Просто перетащи его из папки с компа мышкой в папку со спрайтами в юнити)) Если вопрос об этом

Comment: Вы хотите сделать пол, который будет состоять из повторяющихся нарисованных вами блоков земли? Тогда вам нужен [Sprite Shape](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/09/20/intro-to-2d-world-building-with-sprite-shape/)

Answer (score 0):

Перенеси спрайт в Unity, потом нажми на него, и в правой части экрана (там где Inspector), выбери Sprite(если в картинке спрайт не 1, то выбери MultiPlay sprite). Потом нажми на spriteEditor потом Automatic и потом прими, и все готово.

Comment: Я не знаю как картинку из Paint'a перенести в Unity, у меня с этим проблема, и я хочу узнать как это сделать

Comment: Попробуй так- найди проект на диске, зайди в папку Assets, и перенеси туда, потом зайди в Unity и все готово