# Нужна помощь с платформером

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я нарисовал блок земли в Paint'e и хочу его перенести в 2D платформер, в качестве пола, как мне его туда перенести? Чтобы из папки с файлом изображением блока, перенесся в Unity  и я мог его использовать?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как загрузить спрайт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1217793/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82)

Comment: чел, любой тутор на ютубе...

Answer (score 1):

А не легче перенести Файл с рисунком земли в папку проекта Unity? Ты не всё уточнил и я мог неправильно понять вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо (большое), помогло